# "#" keyCode = 222 vs 51 (Chrome vs Chrome for Android) - why the difference?

Tags: javascript, keycode

Typing `#` gives inconsistent keyCodes on Android:

```
Chrome on Ubuntu 14.10:  "#" keyCode = 222
Chrome on Android 4.4.4: "#" keyCode = 51
```

Why is that??

```
onkeyup=alert(event.keyCode);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The keycode values are not all standardized across browsers. There's a table of the differences [at javascripter.net](http://www.javascripter.net/faq/keycodes.htm), where they say:

> No, unfortunately, not all key codes are standardized. For example,
>   the minus key has different key codes in different browsers.

Other examples they cite of keycodes commonly different between browsers are `;:`, `=+`, and `-_`.